# Reuse ansible variable to create new ones

Tags: ansible

When working with variables all solution I could find for combining variables are pointing into the tasks.

As an example I have following `vars/main.yml` inside my role:

```yaml
netbox_version: 3.7.3
netbox_source: https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox/archive/refs/tags/v3.7.3.tar.gz
```

So instead of repeating the version number at to places, how could I achieve that `netbox_version` is used in `netbox_source`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    netbox_version: 3.7.3
    netbox_source: "path/v{{ netbox_version }}.tar.gz"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: netbox_source
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -l localhost pb.yml 
  ...
ok: [localhost] => 
  netbox_source: path/v3.7.3.tar.gz
```

Put the above *vars* into your *vars/main.yml* (I'd rather put it into the *defaults/main.yml*).

See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

Comment: tested and confirmed. So basic usage of the double-curly-braces syntax also works fine inside of `vars/main.yml` and `default/main.yml` aslong the used variable is defined before?

Comment: There is no order of evaluation. The variables are evaluated when needed. See [Lazy Evaluation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Lazy-Evaluation). You don't have to declare *netbox_version* until *netbox_source* is evaluated at runtime. See [Defining variables at runtime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime).